# Swing ImageIcon causing error and not making image appear

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource, imageicon

I am having a problem with my java project. I am trying to make a JFrame with a background image, but when I use javax.swing.ImageIcon to set the icon of the background JLabel it shows an exception error in the console when I run the program and the image doesn't work, only showing a blank JFrame. Here is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainUI extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainUI().build(); // Calls build method
    }
    private void build() {
        // Builds JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel base = new JPanel();
        JLabel background = new JLabel();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Space Age");
        frame.setSize(640,480);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setAutoRequestFocus(false);
        frame.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        base.setSize(640,480);
        base.setAlignmentX(0.0F);
        base.setAlignmentY(0.0F);
        base.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,255,255));
        background.setSize(640,480);
        background.setAlignmentX(0.0F);
        background.setAlignmentY(0.0F);
        background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("spaceage.images.starfield.png")));
        frame.add(base);
        frame.add(background);
    }
}
```

This is what the error message looks like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at spaceage.src.MainUI.build(MainUI.java:36)
    at spaceage.src.MainUI.main(MainUI.java:15)
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong and how to to make the image display properly?
Thanks in advance,
Santiago

Comment: In all likelihood, you are loading an image from a path that doesn't exist; try `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/spaceage/images/starfield.png")))`. Note the addition of the '/' character. Also, the '.' that you see are actually sub-folders

Comment: I've already tried that; it is the same as using the dots. The error still happens with the slashes, so I don't think it has anything to do with with the path to the image.

Comment: Yeah, in my experience, loading images for a .jar file is so much harder than using the full file paths and almost seems to require voodoo to work properly. I got it working in one of my projects, after numerous attempts by using an `images` package and calling `getClass().getResource("/images/tileset.png")`

Comment: The `String` passed to `getResource` should have slashes as indicated in the first comment of @Aarowaim.  Don't use dots.  It is also case sensitive. So `"/spaceage/images/starfield.png" != "/spaceage/images/StarField.png"`  *"I don't think it has anything to do with with the path to the image"*  Think again.  The path is the problem 99.99% of the time when an NPE is thrown by `ImageIcon`.  In fact, I cannot recall a single instance of it being otherwise, but threw in the .01 % leeway to account for JVM bugs.

Comment: I set the path to "/spaceage/images/starfield.png" and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I did wrong. This:

```
background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("spaceage.images.starfield.png")));
```

needed to be changed to this:

```
background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/spaceage/images/starfield.png")));
```

I got a `NullPointerException` because I entered the path to my image incorrectly, so `getResource()` couldn't find the image and returned `null`.

Answer (score -1):

Also this will help you. You can link it with your requirement.
you can use this-

```
ImageIcon iid = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ranig\\My\\spaceinvaders\\ball.png");
```

Note: C:\Users\ranig\My\spaceinvaders\ball.png is the whole path of ball.png image.

instead of this:

```
ImageIcon iid = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("ball.png"));
```